# Magento 1.6 possible to install extensions using connect 1.0

Tags: magento

I need an extension installed for my Magento 1.6 install,
however the extension only has the old 1.0 protocol and no other extension is available.

is it possible to install, the connect manager states that the key is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry found the answer in case its useful for anyone else:

use the url:
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/name_of_extension